# Removing blank fields and duplicates

Tags: vba, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

This function works.

```
Public Shared Function RemoveDuplicates(ByVal items As Object())  As String()
    System.Array.Sort(items)
    Dim k As Integer = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To items.Length - 1
        If i > 0 AndAlso items(i).Equals(items(i - 1)) Then
            Continue For
        End If
        items(k) = items(i)
        k += 1
    Next
    Dim unique As [String]() = New [String](k - 1) {}
    System.Array.Copy(items, 0, unique, 0, k)
    Return unique
End Function
```

I'd like to add a condition to remove the " " field.

I am using this within a Lookupset

```
=Join(Code.RemoveDuplicates(LookupSet(Fields!Fund_Family.Value &Fields!Portfolio_Company_Name.Value,Fields!Fund_Family.Value & Fields!Portfolio_Company_Name.Value,Fields!Security_Name.Value, "DataSet1")), " / ")
```

I am getting a result that looks like the following:
/Partners
/Orchids
TwentySomething

Comment: Can't you just add `AND items(i) != " "` in your IF statement?

Comment: Public Shared Function RemoveDuplicates(ByVal items As Object())  As String()
System.Array.Sort(items)
Dim k As Integer = 0
For i As Integer = 0 To items.Length - 1
If i > 0 AndAlso items(i).Equals(items(i - 1)) And items(i) != " " Then
Continue For
End If
items(k) = items(i)
k += 1
Next
Dim unique As [String]() = New [String](k - 1) {}
System.Array.Copy(items, 0, unique, 0, k)
Return unique
End Function 

This errored out for me.

Comment: Oh yeah, in VBA the inequality operator is `<>`. But looking at that again, we want that to be an `OR` condition. In other words, if it's blank then skip it.

Comment: That did work syntactically...but now all rows for that column appear as blank.

Comment: Would you be able to tell me why the following gives me an error when there is no value for the entire field. =Join(Code.RemoveDuplicates(LookupSet(Fields!Fund_Family.Value &Fields!Portfolio_Company_Name.Value,Fields!Fund_Family.Value & Fields!Portfolio_Company_Name.Value,Fields!Security_Name.Value, "DataSet1")), " / ").Remove(1,1)

If I get rid of the Remove(1,1) it seems to work without any issues.

Comment: `.Remove(1,1)` means remove the second character in a string. It doesn't work with empty strings.

Comment: UnderStood....is there something I can do to Not get the error....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to prevent the .Remove(1,1) stating an error. I created a duplicate dataset, eliminated all blank values and then performed a Lookup without the .Remove(1,1). That seemed to do the trick for me.

```
= Join(Code.RemoveDuplicates(LookupSet(Fields!Fund_Family.Val‌​ue &Fields!Portfolio_Company_Name.Value,Fields!Fund_Family.Valu‌​e & Fields!Portfolio_Company_Name.Value,Fields!Security_Name.Val‌​ue, "DataSet4")), " / ")
```

That did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the `remove(1,1)` error by wrapping your function in an `IIf()` function.  This way you only remove the second character from the string if there are at least two characters in the string.

So your function would become

```
IIf(Len(Join(Code.RemoveDuplicates(LookupSet(Fields!Fund_Family.Val‌​ue &Fields!Portfolio_Company_Name.Value,Fields!Fund_Family.Valu‌​e & Fields!Portfolio_Company_Name.Value,Fields!Security_Name.Val‌​ue, "DataSet1")), " / ")) >= 2, Join(Code.RemoveDuplicates(LookupSet(Fields!Fund_Family.Val‌​ue &Fields!Portfolio_Company_Name.Value,Fields!Fund_Family.Valu‌​e & Fields!Portfolio_Company_Name.Value,Fields!Security_Name.Val‌​ue, "DataSet1")), " / ").Remove(1,1), Join(Code.RemoveDuplicates(LookupSet(Fields!Fund_Family.Val‌​ue &Fields!Portfolio_Company_Name.Value,Fields!Fund_Family.Valu‌​e & Fields!Portfolio_Company_Name.Value,Fields!Security_Name.Val‌​ue, "DataSet1")), " / "))
```

To make this more readable, I have replaced your function with `CustomFunction()`

```
IIf(Len(CustomFunction()) >= 2, CustomFunction().Remove(1,1), CustomFunction())
```

Comment: That did not work for me either. It gives me an ERROR where there is no Lookup.

Answer (score 0):

To handle blank field update your Shared Function code as below:

```
Public Shared Function RemoveDuplicates(ByVal items As Object())  As String()
System.Array.Sort(items)
Dim k As Integer = 0
For i As Integer = 0 To items.Length - 1
    If i > 0 AndAlso items(i) <> "" AndAlso items(i).Equals(items(i - 1)) Then
        Continue For
    End If
    items(k) = items(i)
    k += 1
Next
Dim unique As [String]() = New [String](k - 1) {}
System.Array.Copy(items, 0, unique, 0, k)
Return unique
End Function
```

Also, update the LookupSet to handle the blank space as below

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Code.RemoveDuplicates(LookupSet(
Fields!Fund_Family.Value & Fields!Portfolio_Company_Name.Value,
Fields!Fund_Family.Value & Fields!Portfolio_Company_Name.Value,
Fields!Security_Name.Value, "DataSet1"))(0)), "", Join(Code.RemoveDuplicates(LookupSet(
Fields!Fund_Family.Value &Fields!Portfolio_Company_Name.Value,
Fields!Fund_Family.Value & Fields!Portfolio_Company_Name.Value,
Fields!Security_Name.Value, "DataSet1")), " / "))
```

Cheers,
Kirti Singh | Soluzione IT Services